# Does ImageDataGenerator add more images to my dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to do image classification with the Inception V3 model. Does `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras create new images which are added onto my dataset? If I have 1000 images, will using this function double it to 2000 images which are used for training? Is there a way to know how many images were created and now fed into the model?

Answer (score 74):

**Short answer:** 1) All the original images are just transformed (i.e. rotation, zooming, etc.) **every epoch** and then used for training, and 2) [Therefore] the number of images in each epoch is equal to the number of original images you have.

**Long answer:** In each epoch, the [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) applies a transformation on the images you have and use the transformed images for training. The set of transformations includes rotation, zooming, etc. By doing this you're somehow creating new data (i.e. also called *data augmentation*), but obviously the generated images are not totally different from the original ones. This way the learned model may be more robust and accurate as it is trained on different variations of the same image.

You need to set the `steps_per_epoch` argument of `fit` method to `n_samples / batch_size`, where `n_samples` is the total number of training data you have (i.e. 1000 in your case). This way in each epoch, each training sample is augmented only one time and therefore 1000 transformed images will be generated in each epoch.

Further, I think it's worth clarifying the meaning of "augmentation" in this context: basically we are augmenting the images when we use `ImageDataGenerator` and enabling its augmentation capabilities. But the word "augmentation" here does not mean, say, if we have 100 original training images we end up having 1000 images **per epoch** after augmentation (i.e. the number of training images does not increase per epoch). Instead, it means we use a different transformation of each image in each epoch; hence, if we train our model for, say, 5 epochs, we have used 5 different versions of each original image in training (or 100 * 5 = 500 different images in the whole training, instead of using just the 100 original images in the whole training). To put it differently, the total number of **unique images** increases in the whole training from start to finish, and not per epoch.

Comment: If I understand correctly from the manual, "step_per_epoch = n_samples / batch_size" will not do augmentation, because it will simply iterate all the data once. If you want to double the data, should you use step_per_epoch = 2*(n_samples / batch_size) ?

Comment: @captainst Augmentation here does not refer to increasing the number of (totally distinct) training samples. Rather, it is the process of creating different variations of **existing** training samples. Therefore, as I mentioned, the generated images are not totally different from the existing training samples; instead they are just random transformations of them. And that's why it does not make sense to set `steps_per_epoch` to anything other than `n_samples / batch_size`. If you do `step_per_epoch = 2*(n_samples / batch_size)` then each epoch actually will be two epochs of the normal case.

Comment: You could have written much simpler and unambiguous  answer: No.

Comment: @Marko I am sorry, but I think that simple "No" would be ambiguous indeed. Further, it's currently the most highest voted answer for this question, so maybe other people don't find it ambiguous. Anyways, let me know which part is ambiguous or complex for you and I would explain it. Don't forget that SO is not a forum and is supposed to be a **QA knowledge-base** like wikipedia.

Comment: @today, I know, I know, sorry, I pushed it to far. I have same question like OP, and I was reading these answers and left with a feeling that I still don't know anything. I think only OP and I know what we want to now :) So, I'll make few experiments to get that answer :)

Comment: @today Did I get it correct: TLDR - ImageDataGenerator augments the images (means, changes them), but doesn't create new images?

Comment: @NeStack Yes, you got it correctly... if transforming the image does not mean creating a new image ;)

Comment: Reading the Keras doc. for ImageDataGenerator, .flow_from_directory, .fit_generator and @today's answer helped me understand. I've been just staring at them for 2 hours.

Comment: @today, you tell me how can we use the speciality or ```ImageDataGenerator``` but for multi-output Neural Networks?  ```flow()``` throws an error if you pass a list of ```y_labels```. How can that be implemented?

Comment: So, how can one 'actually' augment and increase the number of images?

Comment: @NaveenKumar Basically we are augmenting the images when we use `ImageDataGenerator` and enabling its augmentation capabilities. But the word "augmentation" here does not mean, say, if we have 100 original training images we end up having 1000 images **per epoch**. Instead, it means we use a different transformation of each image in each epoch; hence, if we train our model for, say, 5 epochs, we have used 5 different versions of each original image in training (or 100 * 5 = 500 different images in the whole training, instead of using just the 100 original images in the whole training).

Comment: @today, I understood that, thanks to your answer and explanation in comments. But, intent behind my question was to know about a way to increase the number of images and train with same images(increased) every epoch, but with different images for each batch.

Comment: @NaveenKumar If you really want to achieve that (for whatever reason which I am not aware of) you can set the `steps_per_epoch` to a higher number than the actual number of batches, so that the number of batches generated increases. Although, I have not seen this being done commonly and does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 32):

Here is my attempt to answer as I also had this question on my mind.

`ImageDataGenerator` will NOT add new images to your data set in a sense that it will not make your epochs bigger. Instead, in each epoch it will provide slightly altered images (depending on your configuration). It will always generate new images, no matter how many epochs you have.

So in each epoch model will train on different images, but not too different. This should prevent overfitting and in some way simulates online learning.

All these alterations happen in memory, but if you want to see these images you can save them to disc, inspect them, see how many of them were generated and get the sense of how `ImageDataGenerator` works. To do this pass `save_to_dir=/tmp/img-data-gen-outputs` to function `flow_from_directory`. See [docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

Comment: can I somehow save the images with their labels?

Answer (score 8):

As is officially written [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) `ImageDataGenerator` is a  batches Generator of tensor image data with real-time data augmentation. The data will be looped over (in batches). This means that will on the fly apply transformations to batch of images **randomly**. For instance:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, #scale images from integers 0-255 to floats 0-1.
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2, # zoom in or out in images
    horizontal_flip=True) #horizontal flip of images
```

At every new epoch new random transformations will be applied and in this way we train with a little different set of images each time. Obtaining more data is not always achievable or possible, using `ImageDataGenerator` is helpful this way.

Comment: One more unanswer that simply does not answer the question clearly and unambiguously. Couldn't you just write "yes" or "no" at the end?

Comment: what about multi output problems? ```flow()``` throws an error if you pass a list of ```y_labels```. How can that be implemented?

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on how many epochs you run, as @today answered, fitting the model with the generator will make the generator provide as many images as needed, depending on `steps_per_epoch`.

To make things easier to understand, put i.e. 20 images into two whatever folders (mimicking classified data), create a generator out of the parent folder and run a simple for loop

```
count = 0
for image, label in my_test_generator:
    count += 1
    print(count)
```

The first thing you should confirm that you see the message `Found 20 images belonging to 2 classes.`, and the loop itself will NOT stop after 20 iterations, but it will just keep incrementing and printing endlessly (I got mine to 10k and stopped it manually). The generator will provide as many images as are requested, whether they were augmented or not.

Answer (score 3):

Also note that: These augmented images are not stored in the memory, they are generated on the fly while training and lost after training. You can't read again those augmented images.

Not storing those images is a good idea because we'd run out of memory very soon storing huge no of images

Answer (score 1):

> ImageDataGenerator class ensures that the model receives new
> variations of the images at each epoch. But it only returns the
> transformed images and does not add it to the original corpus of
> images. If it was, in fact, the case, then the model would be seeing
> the original images multiple times which would definitely overfit our
> model.

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/08/image-augmentation-on-the-fly-using-keras-imagedatagenerator/

Answer (score 1):

Let me try and tell u in the easiest way possible with the help of an example.
For example:

- you have a set of 500 images
- you applied the `ImageDataGenerator` to the dataset with `batch_size = 25`
- now you run your model for lets say 5 epochs with
  `steps_per_epoch=total_samples/batch_size`
- so , `steps_per_epoch` will be equal to `20`
- now your model will run on all 500 images (randomly transformed according to instructions provided to `ImageDataGenerator`) in each epoch