# Tensorflow ImageDataGenerator Number of Outputs

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, data-augmentation

Please forgive me if this is a silly question, I only recently started using tensorflow's data augmentation capabilities and I want to know how tell how many different variation the ImageDataGenerator produces for each inputed image.

A copy of the specific code I'm using is below.

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(zoom_range = 0.1,
                                                    height_shift_range = 0.1,
                                                    width_shift_range = 0.1,
                                                    rotation_range = 10)
```

Thanks for any help you can give or resource you can point me towards.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748514/2099607) and its answers help you?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot for the link.