# How to get the number of new augmented images generated using Keras Image Processing?

Tags: keras

Based on the code below, if we have 100 images per class, how much new images will be generated using the following data generator?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    shear_range=10,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "data/train", save_to_dir="data",
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="binary",
    target_size=(224,224))
```

Comment: The practical way to achieve that is setting the "save_to_dir" and check the number of images. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to get total images augmented.

Comment: It's a generator, so you can generate an infinite amount of batches of 'new' images from your original images. In practice, you will fix the number of images to be generated by specifying a number of epochs and a number of steps per epoch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ImageDataGenerator add more images to my dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748514/does-imagedatagenerator-add-more-images-to-my-dataset)

Comment: @sdcbr but there is no clear way to check the real number of new images based on the ranges provided (shear, zoom etc.), by iteration/epoch. Generally, I like to take into account the total number of images trained.

Comment: The total number of images trained upon will be equal to the (number of epochs * batch size * steps_per_epoch)

Comment: Great @sdcbr, thank you.

Comment: @today Not a duplicate. There's a huge difference in asking will it add more images AND "how many transformations per image will be performed".

Comment: @shy-tan "how many transformations per image will be performed" ..Sorry, but if you read the linked question and its answers, I think you will realize that it's exactly the same question. At least, that's how I understood it almost 3 years ago and still do.