# The effect of batch_size in ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-augmentation

I am new to Keras and am trying to do data augmentation but I am stuck at the start itself.

I am having an image and I am trying to make augmentations of it as follows;

```
datagen=image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20)
iter=datagen.flow(samples,batch_size=2)
batch=iter.next()
plt.imshow(batch[0].astype('uint8'))
```

So I understand that `datagen` is a generator and `iter` is an iterator to iterate upon it but my doubt is regarding the `batch_size`. Here, `the batch_size=2`, it means during each iteration, a batch of 2 images is created. Now I am able to see the first image in the batch using `batch[0]` as shown above but not able to see the second image of the batch using `batch[1]`. When I check the `batch.shape`, it displays `(1,399,640,3)`which means there is only one image in the batch. I am not able to understand it. Where is the second image?  How can I display the second image of the batch.

Comment: Works fine for me on TF 2.1 (i.e. gives a 2 images in a batch). What's the shape of `samples`? Are you using Keras or tf.Keras?

Comment: I am using Keras and the shape of samples is `(1,399,640,3)`

Comment: If your sample size is < batch_size you'd get only sample-size-many samples in the batch. Because that's all what the ImageDataGenerator has to work with in a single epoch

Comment: Ok you mean to say that I need to change `(1,399,640,3)` to `(2,399,640,3)`. Can you please guide how can this be done?

Comment: Yes, the first dimension of your `samples` need to be >=2 if you need to have 2 items in a batch. How you do that? Well, you need more images in your dataset (or if this is a toy experiment, use `np.repeat(samples, n, axis=0)` where `n` is the number of samples you need in the dataset.

Comment: Here is a good answer to understand batch_size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51748870/1934211

Comment: Do we need the ImageDataGenerator's batch_size to be the same than the batch during the model fitting?