# In ImageDataGenerator data is augmented in each batch or each epoch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-preprocessing

I know that in each epoch we have a new set of augmentation. But my question is that if we have a total of 10 sample image, `batch_size = 5`, and  we took `steps_per_epoch = 3` instead of 2, then we will pass `5*3 = 15` images in each epoch,

so definitely we will have repetition, my question is that if image `x` is repeated, will both have the same augmentation value or different.
It depends on whether new augmentation happens in each batch or in each epoch.

Thanks,

Comment: `ImageDataGenerator` is used for real time image augmentation like random cropping, zooming, translating, etc. It will generate `15` new images from your original `10` images as per your `batch_size`  & `steps_per_epoch` with these transformations randomly applied. It will not simply batch your data, so we won't have repeated images.

Comment: You are saying that each next image has new random augmentation instead of waiting for that epoch or batch to finish?

Comment: No, this will not generate 15 new images once as this could lead to memory constrains on larger datasets. `ImageDataGenerator` works similar to a python `generator`. Images are generated at the fly when the program needs them.

Comment: I am not able to understand your answer clearly, I am saying when will new augmentation will happen , 1) on every next image, 2) on every next batch, 3) on every next epoch

Comment: At the start of every epoch, the number of images needed for that epoch will be generated. For your use case, at the beginning of every epoch 15 new images will be generated from your original image data. You can refer a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748514/does-imagedatagenerator-add-more-images-to-my-dataset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Augmentation happens epoch-wise and not per batch.**

### Explanation:

```py
train_size = 10 
batch_size = 5
steps_per_epoch = n*(train_size//batch_size) # n is any positive integer
```

How `ImageDataGenerator` works is that, for the 1st epoch it will augment all the 10 images to generate 10 augmented images and then select 1-5 augmented images for the 1st step of training. This means that your data to be used for training is defined by the epoch. In the 2nd step for the 1st epoch the next set of augmented images, that is, 6-10 will be used.

In the 2nd epoch, a new set of augmented images will be generated and then for each step, the defined number of images will be used. So if you use 3 steps per epoch then 5 images from the set of 10 augmented images will be repeated.

Comment: so if steps_per_epoch = 3 then in one epoch it will take 15 images , so same image will be sent multiple times for training in one epoch with same augmentation value?

Comment: yes, for every step per epoch the set of images will be selected from those 10 augmented images only. So naturally if you use 3 steps per epoch, 5 images will be repeated

Comment: Great , one more related query I had so I am asking here only, 
If we had `train_size = 12` and `batch_size=5` and `steps_per_epoch = 2` , so 10 images in each epoch will be passed .
But we have total 12 images, so what will happen with other 2 , will it ever be passed or always discarded in each epoch ?

Comment: My bad! those 2 images will be used in the next epoch.

Comment: So there are 2 batches in the 1st epoch and the remaining 2 images are added to the next epoch as the process is still generating for the 1st  set of 12 images in epoch 1. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: check this explanation if the above one was unclear: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10164#issuecomment-388635631